# Is there a way to install an npm package locally but not affect package.json or package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, package.json, .npmrc

I have a project that I'm working on for a client where I have two private packages (which I can't get access to npm install) are inside the package.json.

I do however have access to clone the repos for those said packages. If I simply run an `npm install` I'll get a permission denied error. Same if I run npm link to the packages.

I've been working around this by removing the packages from the package.json then running `npm install ../some-package`. This works but isn't a great solution because if I wanted to add a new package I'd have to deal with a bit of a mess with the package.json.

Is there a better way than this?

I have tried running `npm link ../some-package` but I still get access denied. The only way I've managed to complete an install is by removing the packages then installing them from a local dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the details of your situation, but I see at least two potential solutions to explore.

### Option 1: Install the package from the repo

> I do however have access to clone the repos for those said packages.

You can install from a git repo and `package.json` will record that git repo as the source of the package rather than the npm registry.

From the docs at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install:

> npm install :
>
> Installs the package from the hosted git provider, cloning it with git. For a full git remote url, only that URL will be attempted.

### Option 2: Install from the local file system with --no-save

If that approach doesn't work for you, you can try `npm install --no-save ../some-package` as a build step. The `--no-save` makes it so it doesn't modify `package.json`.